# UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition is broken on iOS 15?

Tags: swift, ios15, macos-monterey

I had this check in my app for a long time...

if(UIReferenceLibraryViewController.dictionaryHasDefinition(forTerm: word))

Suddenly, I don't get any errors but every word string i pass it returns false.

Both Mac and iPhone recently upgraded is this OS issue? Monterey 12.1 and iOS 15.1.1

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Updated to iOS 15.2 today and it seems to have solved the issue.